# Unable to build libuv

Tags: libuv

I'm trying to build libuv 0.11.24 on a Debian machine. I tried:

```
./gyp_uv.py -f make
make -C out
```

I get this error:

```
make: Entering directory `./out'
  LINK(target) ./out/Debug/run-benchmarks
flock: g++: No such file or directory
make: *** [./out/Debug/run-benchmarks] Error 69
make: Leaving directory `./out'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Error:

```
flock: g++: No such file or directory
```

Indicates that you've not installed a c++ compiler. Because this is a debian system, you need to install the appropriate package(s), which are at a minimum `build-essential`, which should pull in `g++`:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

The next question is, why aren't you just installing the system provided version of libuv? The one that you should be able to install using `apt-get install libuv-dev` ?

Comment: Ah, now that you mention it, the error message is clear that g++ isn't installed. (Now I'm a little embarassed.) Thank you very much. As for why I'm not using `libuv-dev`, it's because I use Wheezy and that package isn't available. I could get it through a jessie/sid mirror, but since it's a little outdated, I prefer to build it myself.

Answer (score 0):

'make -C' takes a directory as an argument -- it enters that directory and calls make from there.  in this case it's looking for a directory called 'out' which doesn't exist.  have you tried just calling make?

Comment: Prior to calling `make`, there is a script I have to execute, called 'gyp_uv.py', and this generates the Makefile in the *out* directory.